# iOS 8 Keyboard resets view controller to storyboard positions

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios8, ipad

I have an app with a sign in/sign up view controller. By default, the sign up form is off screen and slides in when the user presses the register button.

On iOS8, opening the keyboard by clicking on one of the text fields on the signup form makes the views reset to their storyboard positions (i.e the registration form off screen).

I tried it by setting the registration view to be overlaid on top in the storyboard, but hiding it in viewDidLoad. Pressing one of the sign in fields makes the registration view suddenly appear on top.

So the problem seems to be the keyboard reloading the view positions from storyboard. Or perhaps the autolayout?

Any help with this is appreciated

***Update***

I disabled Auto Layout and the problem seems to be fixed. However I want to use auto layout, so this isn't great.

***Edit for code***

This is the code used to move the registration form view in to place. It moves the view in

```
- (IBAction)openRegisterForm:(id)sender {
    _registrationViewOpen = YES;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                 animations:^{
                     [[self leftBar] setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - self.leftBar.frame.size.width, 0, self.leftBar.frame.size.width, self.leftBar.frame.size.height )];
                     [registrationForm setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, registrationForm.frame.size.width, registrationForm.frame.size.height)];
                 }];
}
```

Comment: How did you move the view into the visible portion of the view? Did you animate the according constraints? Would be great if you could post some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by animating constraints as opposed to the view itself.

In Interface building I made `IBOutletConnection`s to the relevant constraints (in this case leading edge from superview) and changing the `constraint.constant` in the animate block.

In order to make it animate call `view.layoutIfNeeded`

Note: in iOS8 you need to call `.layoutIfNeeded` on the superview of the view you wish to move